# What does "it's more of a challenge to think of a place I haven't" mean?

Tags: ellipsis

I asked one of my friends a question:

> What is the most weirdest place you ever got drunk?

He replies at this point

> It's more of a challenge to think of a place I haven't.

What does that mean? 
English is not my native language so really donno what it's really all about.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: *weird**est*** includes 'most'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He omitted some of his words. It is inferred from the previous statement (= your statement). Since you were talking about places where you've gotten drunk, we have

> You: What is the most weirdest place you ever got drunk?
>
> Friend: It's more of a challenge to think of a place I haven't **[got(ten) drunk]**.

He's joking and saying it's harder to think of the places where he hasn't been drunk.

By the way, *weirdest* is superlative, so *most* is unnecessary.

Comment: Difficult not easier*       as far as i think

Comment: You're right. I had another joke in mind: _it's easier to think of/name/count the places where I haven't done X_.

Comment: Yes he's kind of saying that it'd be much easier for him to think of the places where he has got drunk instead of the places where he hasn't. Looks like he's such an alcoholic . Aint he? 

Comment: Yeah probably :p

Comment: You really helped me a lot so I'm just gonna hit that right icon and turn it green. #thank_you :)

Comment: I'm glad I helped, but don't be afraid to [wait longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting. It gives others a chance to review answers and make sure they're accurate, among other benefits.

Comment: @Max With such a high reputation as yours I doubt somebody will mind your answer on this one.